# How to remote Tinker Board Asus

Tags: operating-system, pi, vnc, debian-buster, vnc-viewer

I am using Tinker Board and I want remote desktop it from other network. I tried Real VNC and AnyDesk but it don't work. My OS is debian 10, who can help me. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `x11vnc` as long as your distribution uses Xorg as display server. I'm sure that it does.

- Install x11vnc with `sudo apt install x11vnc`.
- Run x11vnc with `x11vnc -noxdamage -norepeat -display :0 -rfbport 5900 -shared`